# Need a way to save a meteor.collection as a text file on a mobile

Tags: android, mobile, meteor, collections, export-to-text

a newbie to Meteor, but I have created under localhost a simple passenger counter I intend to use on an android app for a passenger survey (holding a laptop in an airport isn't a particularly wise idea). It works, but there is no export function. Basically uses meteor.collection as simple rows of data - one row been one passenger with a date/time stamp, two buttons - Add Passenger and Reset. I have tried looking everywhere for a simple answer, but what I want to do is now add to the client side (on browser - but ultimately on the mobile) a button called export, and when clicked, takes each row in the meteor.collection and export it to a text file - line by line. Very simple. Alas right now I haven't got a clue how to proceed. Seen some references to FS.collection, but don't think there is what I want. This is ultimately for a mobile application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. *JSON.stringify* each object into a larger object of pure text, say *bytes*
2. Create a blob from that text object, ex: `blob = new Blob([bytes]);`
3. Use the [filesaver](https://atmospherejs.com/pfafman/filesaver) package to save to a file locally.

Comment: Looking into an alternative solution for mobiles of sending data string (json) to a remote server via post method.

Comment: Yes, will work on Android. You could view the file on iOS as well but there's no user-accessible file system to save it to. You're right that you're better off trying to get the app to communicate directly with a server instead of mucking with files.

Comment: Hi just letting other people know that filesaver package won't work as a standalone android mobile app - appears to do nothing when event triggered - modified my code to be client only :-(